# Does overloading a parents function circumvent polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading

A parent class has a function which accepts any child as a parameter. I know that if the child class is the same type as the parameter a significant optimization can be made. I have been taught that things like dynamic_cast to check for types is bad design. Therefore my solution has been to write an entirely separate function which overloads the parents function and has a parameter of type child. Does this circumvent polymorphism in a bad way?

```
class parent{
  virtual void foo(parent& bar) =0;
}
class child: public parent{
  void foo(parent& bar){
    //unoptimized code
  }
  void foo(child& bar){
    //optimized code
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be overriding the function if it is declared virtual in the superclass. All subclasses inherit the `virtual`ness of functions in their superclass.

Answer (score 0):

You may do

```
struct parent{
  virtual ~parent() = default;
  virtual void foo(parent& bar) = 0;
};

struct child: public parent{
  void foo(parent& bar) override {
    if (child* c = dynamic_cast<child*>(&bar)) {
        foo(*c); // call optimized code
        return;
    }
    //unoptimized code
  }
  void foo(child& bar){ // This one is not an override
    //optimized code
  }

};
```

or use multidispatch

```
struct parent{
  virtual ~parent() = default;
  virtual void foo(parent& bar) = 0;

  virtual void foo_called_by(child& c) = 0;
  // other derived class as
  virtual void foo_called_by(child2& c) = 0;

};

struct child: public parent{
  void foo(parent& bar) override { bar.foo_called(*this); }
  void foo_called_by(child& bar) override {
    //optimized code
  }

  void foo_called_by(child2& bar) override {
    //unoptimized code
  }

};
```